I want to prevent someone reprotecting a sheet
I've got the below in VBA to protect all my sheets in one go. But someone could press it twice and overwrite the password, then unprotect them all, thus negating the protection.
How can I prevent this from happening? I guess there's also a piece around avoiding workarounds by using the review tab?
I'm thinking check to see if the sheet is protected, if no, then proceed, if yes, flag that the sheet is already protected. How would I go about doing that please?
Sub ProtectAll()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Pwd As String

    Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to protect all worksheets", "Password Input")

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.Protect Password:=Pwd, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
        AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True

    Next wSheet
    
    Sheets("Front_Cover").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("All worksheets have been protected.")
End Sub


You may check the Protectcontent property in your loop first.

You don't have to. The Worksheet.Protect method does not overwrite the existing password, nor does it allow to change any activated protection without knowing the previous password.
When you run this code twice, with different passwords

the first time the protection is activated and a password is set

the second time the new password will be ignored, but you won't get an error message, since you did not try to change any permissions on the sheets


You can verify this by running your code twice with different passwords, and try to unprotect manually afterwards - you will see Excel will not accept the second password you entered, only the first one.
Now, when you try to run this macro two times, where the second time you change Contents=True to Contents=False - then you get a run time error "wrong password".
